# Error in server.js cannot fined module 'cookie'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express

I been making a web site based on the example here and I'm trying to implement that server. Although it worked perfectly, after I've added the authentications & cookie codes the server.js stopped working saying cannot find module 'cookie', which I think related to `express-session`

Here is my server.js code;

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var showSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        _id: Number,
        name: String,
        airsDayofWeek: String,
        airsTime: String,
        firstAired: Date,
        genre: [String],
        network: String,
        overview: String,
        rating: Number,
        ratingCount: Number,
        status: String,
        poster: String,
        subscribers: [{
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
            }],
        episodes: [{
                season: Number,
                episodeNumber: Number,
                episodeName: String,
                firstAired: Date,
                overview: String
            }]
    });

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        email: { type: String, unique: true },
        password: String
    });

userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    var user = this;
    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
}

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var Show = mongoose.model('Show', showSchema);

mongoose.connect('localhost');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) next();
    else res.send(401);
};

passport.use(new new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, function (email, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        if (!user) return done(null, false);
        user.comparePassword(password, function (err, isMatch) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            if (isMatch) return done(null, user);
            return done(null, false);
        });
    });
}));



app.get('/api/shows', function (req, res, next) {
    var query = Show.find();
    if (req.query.genre) {
        query.where({ genre: req.query.genre });
    }
    else if (req.query.alphabet) {
        query.where({ name: new RegExp('^' + '[' + req.query.alphabet + ']', 'i') });

    }
    else {
        query.limit(12);
    }
    query.exec(function (err, shows) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(shows);
    });

});

app.get('/api/shows/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    Show.findById(req.params.id, function (err, show) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(show);
    });
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.user) {
        res.cookie('user', JSON.stringify(req.user));
    }
    next();
});

app.post('/api/shows', function (req, res, next) {
    var apiKey = '4B8EA1DCA9C6B577';
    var parser = xml2js.Parser({
        explicitArray: false,
        normalizeTags: true
    });
    var seriesName = req.body.showName
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/ /g, '_')
    .replace(/[^\w-]+/g, '');

    async.waterfall([
        function (callback) {
            request.get('http://thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=' + seriesName, function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) return next(error);
                parser.parseString(body, function (err, result) {
                    if (!result.data.series) {
                        return res.send(404, { message: req.body.showName + ' was not found.' });
                    }
                    var seriesId = result.data.series.seriesid || result.data.series[0].seriesid;
                    callback(err, seriesId);
                });
            });
        },
        function (seriesId, callback) {
            request.get('http://thetvdb.com/api/' + apiKey + '/series/' + seriesId + '/all/en.xml', function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) return next(error);
                parser.parseString(body, function (err, result) {
                    var series = result.data.series;
                    var episodes = result.data.episode;
                    var show = new Show({
                        _id: series.id,
                        name: series.seriesname,
                        airsDayOfWeek: series.airs_dayofweek,
                        airsTime: series.airs_time,
                        firstAired: series.firstaired,
                        genre: series.genre.split('|').filter(Boolean),
                        network: series.network,
                        overview: series.overview,
                        rating: series.rating,
                        ratingCount: series.ratingcount,
                        runtime: series.runtime,
                        status: series.status,
                        poster: series.poster,
                        episodes: []
                    });
                    _.each(episodes, function (episode) {
                        show.episodes.push({
                            season: episode.seasonnumber,
                            episodeNumber: episode.episodenumber,
                            episodeName: episode.episodename,
                            firstAired: episode.firstaired,
                            overview: episode.overview
                        });
                    });
                    callback(err, show);
                });
            });
        },
        function (show, callback) {
            var url = 'http://thetvdb.com/banners/' + show.poster;
            request({ url: url, encoding: null }, function (error, response, body) {
                show.poster = 'data:' + response.headers['content-type'] + ';base64,' + body.toString('base64');
                callback(error, show);
            });
        }
    ], function (err, show) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        show.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code == 11000) {
                    return res.send(409, { message: show.name + ' already exists.' });
                }
                return next(err);
            }
            res.send(200);
        });
    });
});

app.post('/api/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function (req, res){
    res.cookie('user', JSON.stringify(req.user));
    res.send(req.user);
})

app.post('/api/signup', function (req, res, next) {
    var user = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.boy.password
    });
    user.save(function (err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(200);
    });
});

app.get('/api/logout', function (req, res, next) {
    req.logout();
    res.send(200);
});


app.get('*',function (req, res){
    res.redirect('/#' + req.originalUrl);
})

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.send(500, { message: err.message });
});


passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user, id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

Even though I changed the places of the codes still nothing works. Am I missing some modules? or placed codes in the wrong order. I'm a beginner to node.js so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `cookie-parser` in your `package.json`? If not, run ` npm i --save cookie-parser` and restart your app.

Comment: Yes the package hasn't been installed properly. Thanks!

Comment: @SwarajGiri Oh yes thanks, Also gave me another error it says 'id is not defined' in server.js what could that be? I'm trying to figure out with still no results. When I press login, sorry forgot to mention that. Any advice